# JavaScript uncaught Typeerror

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I want to know if the checkbox has been checked via JavaScript. 
The code for Html(PHP) button is :

```
<div class="span8 offset8" style="text-align:right;">
                                        <div class="helpIcon">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" original-title="."></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="skip-analysis" id="emptyFolder"><input type="checkbox" name="emptyFolder" class="_nosearch"> <span>Ignore up to date files</span></span>
```

The JS code is :

```
skipCopy1 = that.element.find('#emptyFolder input[name=emptyFolder]');
console.dir(skipCopy1);
var skipCopy = that.skipCopy1.is(':checked');
console.log('skipcopy 1st '+skipCopy);
```

I get an error in Chrome console saying :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is' of undefined ('is' from Line 15)

Where am I going wrong? i just need True false value in the skipCopy variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you suddenly call it `that.skipCopy1` on that one line? Where does `that` come from?

Comment: maybe `that.skipCopy1`should be `skipCopy1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `skipCopy1` is a variable. If so, remove the `that.` from:

```
var skipCopy = that.skipCopy1.is(':checked');
//             ^^^^^---- remove this
```

***Or***, if you intended `skipCopy1` to be a property of `that`, you need to set it on the previous line:

```
    that.skipCopy1 = that.element.find('#emptyFolder input[name=emptyFolder]');
//  ^^^^^---- add this
```

Comment: Yes skipcopy1 is supposed to be property of that variable :) 
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to use the JQuery library like so:

```
// First method - Recommended
$('#checkbox').prop('checked')  // Boolean true

// Second method - Makes code more readable (e.g. in if statements)
$('#checkbox').is(':checked')  // Boolean true

// Third method - Selecting the checkbox & filtering by :checked selector
$('#checkbox:checked').length  // Integer >0
$('#checkbox:checked').size()  // .size() can be used instead of .length

// Fourth method - Getting DOM object reference
$('#checkbox').get(0).checked  // Boolean true
$('#checkbox')[0].checked      // Boolean true (same as above)
```

HTML:

```
<input id="checkbox"  type="checkbox" name="one" value="1" checked="checked">
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="two" value="2">
<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="thr" value="3">
```

More info: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.be/2013/02/jquery-test-check-if-checkbox-checked.html